# Strange behavior backbone, javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In a view I've an onClick event that call a function:

```
 retweet: function () {
           cb.__call(
                "statuses_retweet_ID",
                "id=472518063737536512",
                function (reply) {
                //gestire rate limit error 429
                 console.log(reply);
                 return reply;
                }
            );
      },
```

The strange behavior is: if don't click and consequently retweet function is not called my application works perfectly but if I click the function is executed but the app crash and some variable will undefined. I can't understand, maybe is the cb.__call function?

Comment: What's in the JS console?

Comment: The console.log(reply) and when I try to scroll down the page,another function is called and appear Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoading' of undefined. This not happen if retweet function is not called @DaveNewton